# how to use glMapBufferRange

Tags: opengl

I have defined a VBO with a section of vertics that will be updated
periodically by a thread.
After creating the VBO and filling its buffers i retrieved the pointer
to the section i want to change.

Should i call glMapBufferRange every time before i change the content
of my array? 
The documentation says it must be unmapped after usage, which means it is invalid then.

My understanding is that the following pseude code has to appear in my update thread

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, null, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
ptr = glMapBufferRange( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, GL_MAP_WRITE_BITGL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT);
 -> populate buffer
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

am i right with that, and is this the best way to manipulate a section of the VBO?

Comment: Chapter 28 of [OpenGL Insights](http://openglinsights.com/) is helpful. You can also download the code.